# How can I use bootstrap-sass with spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, spree

I want to do responsive the spree layouts using bootstrap.. I'm using rails 3.2.14 with spree 2.0.4 and bootstrap-sass 2.3.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start with Jeff Dutil's [spree_bootstrap](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_bootstrap) plugin.  Jeff is a very active member of the Spree community and has done some work to make Spree's interface use Bootstrap.